# Cordova IOS Update issue

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, phonegap-cli

After I update ios 4.1.1 in cordova splash screen not working and App running also half of the screen in my ios device, and its working fine in Simulator. I tried iPhone 5c and iPhone 6.

Cordova version 5.2.0
Cordova ios Version 4.1.1

Comment: Try updating cordova version

Comment: Problem is in Dimension of Splash and Icons of Image files. I Changed that and Error gone...